# What is the name of the following electrical symbol?

Tags: electrical

What is the name of the following symbol (in red)  :

[image]

This is from the front wiper motor schematic of a Toyota Corolla car.
First time I have seen this. I searched a little bit on various websites but couldn't find the meaning.

Comment: It may be part of the self-parking circuit. When the wipers are switched off the motor should run until in the park position. These are generally a curved segment and brush in the gearbox. It's not clear though without the rest of the circuit. As show it would seem to cut the common return from the 2-speed motor on every cycle with no way to restart it. Does the elliptical symbol on the other switch represent a cam?

Comment: AFAIK park mode is implemented using the 3 way switch. It connect +S wire to either ground (E wire) or positive terminal (B wire). The switch is in reality a rotating disk (it is connected to a gear that rotate along with motor). On the schema it is shown as a cam but it does the same thing.  I think +2/+1 is for fast/slow mode. You can view more in the video I posted in Marcus answer.

Comment: My guess is a bimetallic strip to shut off the motor if it starts to overheat.

Comment: It's a cheshire cat

Comment: Its a cooking WOK.

Comment: Most of the curved symbols are some type of capacitor,

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a standardized symbol.

I'd assume that it's a sickle-shaped contacting thing connected mechanically to the wiper.

Comment: I was going to guess "mechanical slider"...  maybe it changes resistance(?).  Try searching "ANSI electrical symbols" or "IEEE Standard 315" and see if anything shows up.

Comment: There is a disassembly of similar motor here : https://youtu.be/Pa4jv8FvjAQ. At 5:37 is the schematic, with similar symbol. The only contacting part I can see is the rotating disk with the 3 pins and the motor brushes.

Comment: I agree with @tigrou.  Not sure how the toothbrush fits in though... maybe that is his brother's too.  Maybe you could message him on youtube... He seems to be a wiper motor expert.  Who knew there were any?